# Screwed up in caustic 3. Want to delete recorded notes

Tags: synthesizer, daw, windows

In Caustic 3 I activated de red record button and played some notes for testing purposes using a synth and now I can't delete the recorded part.
I can't see it in the pattern tab of that synth neither in the global song tab.
What do I do? I don't want to delete the synth I already set up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you may have recorded in Song mode, as opposed to Pattern mode.

To find your Song recorded notes:
Go into the Sequencer module, change to Song mode at the bottom, then tap the button at the top left of the screen that looks like a grid.  This puts you into the piano roll for Song, and the button changes to keyboard icon.  Tap the text box next to that button to select the synth you recorded on.  You should find your notes on that piano roll.

To get back to sequencer mode, tap the button at the top left twice.  (That button toggles through the 3 modes of the sequencer, the third being automation controls)